# Why are my json attributes bouncing off in POST in Sinatra?

Tags: json, sinatra

I hope someone can share their knowledge with me. I have a small Sinatra app that I want to POST json data to it. The record is being created, thankfully, but none of the attributes make it. I've read several JSON examples using curl but they all yield the same result. So it makes me think it's my model. I can create records using tux fine so perhaps it's not my model.

```
 curl command:

 curl -XPOST -H "Content-Type: application/json" 
 "localhost:4567/date" -d 
 '{ "post": { "title": "different tile here"}}'

 curl output:

 => {"id":13,"title":null,"body":null,"created_at":"2014-04-21T18:13:53Z",
"updated_at":"2014-04-21T18:13:53Z"}
```

sinatra output:

```
     [2014-04-27T20:03:48.035710 #45360] DEBUG -- :    (0.1ms)  commit transaction
  127.0.0.1 - - [27/Apr/2014 20:03:48] "POST /date HTTP/1.1" 200 - 0.0181
  {"post":{"title":"different tile here"}}
  D, [2014-04-27T20:09:32.614274 #45360] DEBUG -- :    (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  D, [2014-04-27T20:09:32.615917 #45360] DEBUG -- :   SQL (0.4ms)  INSERT INTO "posts"         ("created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?)  [["created_at", 2014-04-28 01:09:32 UTC],    ["updated_at", 2014-04-28 01:09:32 UTC]]
 D, [2014-04-27T20:09:32.617656 #45360] DEBUG -- :    (1.5ms)  commit transaction
 D, [2014-04-27T20:09:32.617852 #45360] DEBUG -- :    (0.1ms)  begin transaction
 D, [2014-04-27T20:09:32.618132 #45360] DEBUG -- :    (0.0ms)  commit transaction
 127.0.0.1 - - [27/Apr/2014 20:09:32] "POST /date HTTP/1.1" 200 - 0.0070
 D, [2014-04-27T20:09:57.796909 #45360] DEBUG -- :   Post Load (0.3ms)  SELECT     "posts".* FROM "posts" ORDER BY created_at DESC
 127.0.0.1 - - [27/Apr/2014 20:09:57] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 2149 0.0128
```

app.rb

```
 require 'sinatra'
 require 'sinatra/activerecord'
 require './environments'
 require 'sinatra/flash'
 require 'sinatra/redirect_with_flash'
 require 'json'

 class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
 end

 post "/posts" do
   @post = Post.new(params[:post])
   if @post.save
     redirect "posts/#{@post.id}"
   else
     erb :"posts/create"
   end
 end

 post '/date', :provides => 'json' do
   data = JSON.parse(request.body.read)
   json_data = data.to_json

   content_type :json
   #@post = Post.new(params)

   @post = Post.create(
     title: data[:title]
     body: data[:body]
     )

   if @post.save
     @post.to_json
   else
     halt 500
   end
 end

 get "/posts/create" do
   @title = "Create post"
   @post = Post.new
   erb :"posts/create"
 end

 get "/posts/:id" do
@post = Post.find(params[:id])
@title = @post.title
erb :"posts/view"
 end

 get "/" do
@posts = Post.order("created_at DESC")
@title = "Welcome."
erb :"posts/index"
 end
```

Gemfile

```
 source 'https://rubygems.org'
 ruby "2.0.0"

 gem "sinatra"
 gem 'activerecord', '4.0.4'
 gem "sinatra-activerecord"
 gem 'sinatra-flash'
 gem 'sinatra-redirect-with-flash'
 gem 'json'

 group :development do
   gem 'sqlite3'
   gem "tux"
 end

 group :production do
   gem 'pg'
 end
```

environments.rb

```
 configure :development do
set :database, 'sqlite3:///dev.db'
set :show_exceptions, true
 end

 configure :production do
db = URI.parse(ENV['DATABASE_URL'] || 'postgres:///localhost/mydb')

ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
    adapter: db.scheme == 'postgres' ? 'postgresql' : db.scheme,
    host: db.host,
    username: db.user,
    password: db.password,
    database: db.path[1..-1],
    encoding: 'utf9'
    )
 end
```

I've left off my layout files since I'm testing this POST via this rudimentary API. I've bounced around the few examples of Sinatra API's on the web and don't know what I'm not seeing. What am I overlooking here? It's almost like Strong Parameters in Rails 4, but if so why does tux allow me to create records? thanx, sam

Comment: Aside from using tabs instead of spaces to indent your code, this looks generally alright ;) Have you tried using the [`, :provides => 'json'` condition](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro#Conditions) on the routes?

Comment: It looks like you almost worked it out – why have you commented out the line `#data = JSON.parse(request.body.read)`?

Comment: An artifact from a previous tutorial.

Comment: I've attempted your suggestions, thanx for offering them.